# When pexpect.spawn is called, does execution of the spawned program start immediately?

Tags: python, pexpect

Are `pexpect.spawn` objects inactive until `expect` (or `interact`, `send`, etc) is called, or does the invoked process start immediately? For example:

```
import pexpect
process = pexpect.spawn("echo HELLO")
print ("Process created? Or run?")
process.expect("HELLO")
```

When the `print` statement occurs, has `pexpect` already run the echo command under the covers and is just holding off on letting it return until the `expect` call is processed? Or has nothing happened (`echo` hasn't run) until the first call to `expect` or similar?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passed a command, `pexpect.spawn()` forks and invokes the command immediately. The echo command in your example would have been run already.

This is implied in the [`spawn` constructor documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn):

> This is the constructor. The command parameter may be a string that
>   includes a command and any arguments to the command. For example::
>
> ```
> child = pexpect.spawn ('/usr/bin/ftp')
> child = pexpect.spawn ('/usr/bin/ssh user@example.com')
> child = pexpect.spawn ('ls -latr /tmp')
> ```
>
> You may also construct it with a list of arguments like so::
>
> ```
> child = pexpect.spawn ('/usr/bin/ftp', [])
> child = pexpect.spawn ('/usr/bin/ssh', ['user@example.com'])
> child = pexpect.spawn ('ls', ['-latr', '/tmp'])
> ```
>
> After this the child application will be created and will be ready to
>   talk to.

I've confirmed this by looking at the [source code](http://pexpect.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pexpect/trunk/pexpect/pexpect.py?revision=HEAD&view=markup); the constructor calls `_spawn()` which is documented as follows:

> This starts the given command in a child process. This does all the
>   fork/exec type of stuff for a pty. This is called by `__init__`. If args
>   is empty then command will be parsed (split on spaces) and args will be
>   set to parsed arguments.